# Use of standard clone button in the VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a object called the Commercial and i have use the standard edit button to rendered into my Commercial Edit VF page. Now i want to use the clone button  but it should not work like edit button. Clone as if means to start the new commercial VF page and work like a new button.
 Also Provide me the Apex code for the same .Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried. Where are you having trouble. You will get a lot more responses if you do some effort yourself. This is not a site for free development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apex a record can be cloned as follows

```
customObject__c newRecord = existingRecord.clone(false,true);

newRecord .status__c = 'New'; //optionally, change any field that you want to be updated in cloned record.

insert newRecord;
```

For more details on the parameters of the clone method, refer the below link.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone